# Passing value as key in Firebase database rule

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have a database where family has members.

**Family member database.**

```
// Family 1 has user 1, user 2, user 3.
// Family 2 has user 4, user 5.
// family_id_x is uniquely generated by firebase.
// uid is uniquely generated by firebase on registration. (auth.uid)
// database 'family-member'
'family-member':[
  'family_id_1': 'uid_1',
  'family_id_1': 'uid_2',
  'family_id_1': 'uid_3'
  'family_id_2': 'uid_4'
  'family_id_2': 'uid_5'
]
```

**Furniture database**

```
// A family member can create furniture for the family.
// database 'furniture'
'furniture':[
  'furniture_id_1': {
    'furnitureName': "Mahogany Dining Table",
    'familyKey': 'family_id_1'
  }
]
```

So I created a database rule to see if the user is able to make a new furniture.
I've logged in with uid_1.
Then I tried the following.

```
// database rule for furniture.
"furniture": {
   ".write": "auth != null && (root.child('family-member').child( 
   newData.child(familyKey).val() // Problem!
   ).child(auth.uid).exists())
}
```

This fails. I suspected the underlined part is the cause. So I hard coded.

```
"furniture": {
   ".write": "auth != null && (root.child('family-member').child( 
   'family_id_1' // HardCode! Now works.
   ).child(auth.uid).exists())
}
```

It works.

Please let me know what I should do in order to solve this problem.

Edit: product => furniture, Miscellaneous syntax errors

Comment: That first bit you shared is not valid JSON: you can't have multiple instances of the same key/family.

Comment: At the very least you'll want `newData.child('familyKey').val()`, with quotes around the `famileyKey` part. But it's hard to be precise without seeing the actual JSON you're using

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen ... It was the quotes. The problem code works fine with the quotes around the keys. I feel ashamed.

Comment: Phew.... good to hear that we found the problem. I vote to close the question as a typo in that case, since other devs in the same situation are unlikely to find this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct me if I am wrong (I may not fully understand what you are asking but would this work):

```
"product": {
   "$familyKey": {
      ".write": "auth != null && (root.child('family-member').child( 
      newData.child(familyKey).val() // Problem!
      ).child(auth.uid).exists())
   }
}
```

This is specifying a variable (a wild card) which you might want to make an `==` type of comparison such as the path you are trying to get might always exist.

```
"root.child('family-member').child($familyKey).val() == family_id_1"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But If I did structure it this way, I'd have a harder time reading products(furniture) as a list. That would mean I have to create another node for just getting a list of products or use complex query to get the data.

Answer (score 0):

It was a simple typo.

I needed to put quotation around the key

```
newData.child(familyKey).val() // Problem!

newData.child('familyKey').val() // Solution!
```

Closing.